# Configuration error in sonarqube in windows 64 bit

Tags: error-handling, configuration, java-8, console, sonarqube

I installed sonarqube in my PC and ran the startsonar in "bin\windows-x86-64" folder in order to start sonarqube. A console appeared and closed like the following pic[image]

I read several stack over flow posts but couldn't find a solution! How can I rectify this?

Comment: check the logs in sonarqube folder/logs. Mostly it could be port already in use issue

Comment: @Chids i changed the port still error occurs

Comment: Did you add extra plugins?

Comment: @JeroenHeier no